# Determine the index with multiple swiper instances

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am using swiperjs to display rows of data on my page which is a react application.
Each row is a swiper instance. If I am swiping on a particular row, how do I get to know
which swiper index I am currently at?
Is there a way to find out when the swipe has begun on a particular row?

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
     this.buildSwiper();
  }
  
    // Initialize the swiper component.
    buildSwiper() {
     this.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: auto,
      freeMode: true,
      freeModeSticky: true,
      simulateTouch: true,
      on: {
        reachEnd: this.onReachEnd
      },
    });
  }
  
  onReachEnd() {
    // **Need help here: I want to append the slide only on the correct row I am swiping at.**
     this.swiper.forEach(swiper => 
        swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>')
      )
  }
  
  renderDepartments(dept) {
    <div className="swiper-container">
        <div className="swiper-wrapper">
          <div className="swiper-slide" key={dept.id}>
            {dept.name}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  }
  
  render() {
    const { departments } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>{departments && departments.map(dept => this.renderDepartments(dept))}</div>
    );
  }

};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectSheet(styles)(Department));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on swiperjs API documentation, `reachEnd` event accepts `swiper` instance as an argument. That is the current swiper you are currently accessing.

```
onReachEnd(swiper) {
  swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>')
}
```